# How to apply a python patch on installed library

Tags: python, libraries, patch, django

I have a linux box with root access. I've django library installed as uncompressed python egg. Now I want to install [this patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/5423/5423.5.diff).

How can I do it?

Comment: Unless you've used the Ubuntu Django (deb) packages and want to re-package it, I don't see how this is ontopic here. Software development and related things like applying patches should be asked on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). But pssst... `cd path/to/django; patch -p2 --dry-run < path/to/patch` will help you out, right?

Comment: Developing for (or in) Ubuntu is a topic of AskUbuntu. Check the FAQ (http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: @JavierRivera made it a Q: [What is meant exactly by “Development on Ubuntu” in the FAQ?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5744/88802)

Comment: @gertvdgik: If he is using this question is ontopic here(and also in SO), deb package is not necessory, You can post your answer below

Comment: Development under Ubuntu and using Ubuntu for developing is more than on-topic for this site. This question stays. @gertvdijk feel free to add an answer to this post, there is nothing wrong with it or that deserves migration any where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the 'patch' tool to apply your patch. The description provided to you above is likely useful; first move to the django source directory or where ever you've uncompressed your egg, and then run patch (if you don't have patch installed simply do an apt-get install patch). I'd use -p1 as an arg, not sure why -p2 was specified, but my command might look like this;

```
patch -p1 --dry-run < name.patch
```

You can find out more with 'man patch'.